# Specify columnsHaveTypes to import data from csv files into Mongodb and specify one field as string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoimport

I have one csv which have data in below format

```
Mobile,Address
1234567890,My address
1234567891,My address
1234567892,My address
+911234567893,My address
+911234567894,My address
```

When I import data into mongodb using below command then + is getting removed from mobile column because mongoimport is inserting mobile as NumberLong.

```
mongoimport --db test -c testcoll  --type csv --file test.csv --headerline
```

But I want to insert the data as it is. SO I tried to store it as string using below command

```
mongoimport --db test -c testcoll  --type csv --columnsHaveTypes --fields \"Mobile.string()"\ --file test.csv --headerline
```

But above command  is not working.

Note: I only want to change data type for mobile column . Other column will be inserted as per mongoimport default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I think you should decide between using the **--fields** or the **--headerline** parameter

You would have either the type specification through **--headerline** in the csv-file with command:

```
mongoimport --db test -c testcoll  --type csv --columnsHaveTypes --headerline --file test.csv
```

```
Mobile.string(),Address.auto()
1234567890,My address
1234567891,My address
1234567892,My address
+911234567893,My address
+911234567894,My address
```

Or you can specify **--fields** in your command :

```
mongoimport --db test -c testcoll  --type csv --columnsHaveTypes --fields 'Mobile.string(),Address.auto()' --file test.csv
```

And remove the header from the csv:

```
1234567890,My address
1234567891,My address
1234567892,My address
+911234567893,My address
+911234567894,My address
```